# Ubuntu installation does not recognize previous partitions

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, installation

I have been attempting to install Ubuntu (10.04, Lucid Lynx) on my computer. I wasn't ready to take the pure-Linux plunge yet, so I reserved a partition on which I would install Ubuntu. I ran the installer and answered the 'minor' questions (keyboard  layout, time zone, etc.), but had trouble when I reached the partitioning. I have several partitions, but Ubuntu only saw one of them, which was not the ext3 partition that I had set up. I tried deleting the partition in hope that the installer would find and utilize the empty space, but it only saw the original partition. I do not have an external hard drive to use, and I cannot clear any existing partitions. Am I running the installer incorrectly, or is there a more serious problem?

Comment: Just in case: are you installing from wubi, which I think puts the ubuntu partition in a big file in the windows filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating these partitions (eg:  what software tool are you using?) that the installer is not recognizing?  Have you tried the latest official (9.10) release instead of the beta (10.04) release?

Comment: I am using Acronis Disk Director. I have not yet tried using the official release; I will try that.

Comment: What the duck? 9.10 is the old version. 10.04 is the very latest STABLE LTS version. 10.10 is the latest ultra-alpha (there is no alpha release yet since 10.04 just came out sometime ago.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you use RAID , LVM , or anything like that ? Check `dmesg`, `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo cfdisk` from the live CD. (These are commands which can be used in a Terminal. So open one and type them in there. You can get a scrollable dmesg with `dmesg | less`.)